# Rendering multiple react components inside <ul> with button onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm new to React, just started learning, and I've run into a problem that I can't seem to find a solution to.

I'm trying to render a react component on click of the button in the modal. Currently it renders properly just one element, (cause of the root, I know that, but i don't know what to change). I want the app to be able to render as many components, as many times user clicks on the add button (they will be exactly the same for now, I know, I just want to see more components being rendered inside the same .

This is my ContactList component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ContactItem from "./ContactItem";
import "./App.css";

class ContactsList extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <ul className="list-group list-group-flush container">
            <ContactItem login="typeofweb1" name="Lena" department="JavaScript Developer" border="0" />
            <ContactItem login="typeofweb2" name="Brian" department="Human Resources" />
            <ContactItem login="typeofweb3" name="Rick" department="QA" />
            <div id="addContactRoot" />
         </ul>
      );
   }
}

export default ContactsList;
```

ContactItem component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class ContactItem extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         counter: 0,
         totalClicks: 0
      };
   }

   render() {
      const imgUrl = `https://api.adorable.io/avatars/55/${this.props.login}.png`;
      return (
         <li className="list-group-item" style={{ padding: "8px", borderTop: this.props.border }}>
            <img src={imgUrl} width="36" height="36" style={{ borderRadius: "5px", float: "left" }} alt="Avatar" />
            <div style={{ float: "left", marginLeft: "10px" }}>
               <p className="font-weight-bold" style={{ fontSize: "15px", marginBottom: "-10px" }}>
                  {this.props.name}
               </p>
               <span style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>{this.props.department}</span>
               <span className="buttons">
                  <button onClick={this.handleIncrement} className="badge badge-warning counter-badge">
                     +
                  </button>
                  <span className="badge badge-primary counter-badge">Score: {this.state.counter}</span>
                  <span className="badge badge-danger counter-badge">Total clicks: {this.state.totalClicks}</span>
                  <button onClick={this.handleDecrement} className="badge badge-warning counter-badge">
                     -
                  </button>
               </span>
            </div>
         </li>
      );
   }

   handleIncrement = () => {
      this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
      this.setState({ totalClicks: this.state.totalClicks + 1 });
   };
   handleDecrement = () => {
      this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter - 1 });
      this.setState({ totalClicks: this.state.totalClicks + 1 });
   };
}

export default ContactItem;
```

And this is the Modal component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ContactItem from "./ContactItem";
import "./App.css";

class Modal extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
               Add
            </button>
            <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
               <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div className="modal-content">
                     <div className="modal-header">
                        <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                           Add contact <i className="fas fa-plus" />
                        </h5>
                        <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                     </div>
                     <div className="modal-body">
                        <div>
                           <img src="https://api.adorable.io/avatars/40/sa@adorable.io.png" style={{ borderRadius: "5px" }} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-group mb-3">
                           <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-group mb-3">
                           <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Department" />
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div className="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                           Close
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
                           Add
                        </button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      );
   }

   handleOnClick = () => {
      ReactDOM.render(<ContactItem login="typeofweb3" name="John" department="Office" />, document.getElementById("addContactRoot"));
   };
}

export default Modal;
```

there is a "Add" button with the onclick, when the users clicks the button i want to render new ContactItem component inside a ContactList component. But I want to be able to render multiple ContactItem components, if I click the add button once, and then later another time.

Sorry if I didn't describe the problem well, or if I wrote the post wrong, this is my first ever post on stackoverflow :)

Comment: I think you need to maintain an array in a parent component's state and on clicking the add button, you just need to push a new element into that array. And your `ul` element would be looping through that array so that it would get updated automatically whenever the array is updated.

Comment: How can I setState of the parent component? ContactList.setState() doesnt seem to work

Comment: Actaully it is not even a parent. Can I call a method from ContactsList component inside Modal component?

Comment: Either you can use shared global state for this using Redux etc. Otherwise simply keep this array in a common parent component and pass in a method as prop that would change the state in parent component.

Comment: Thank you Mohit Bhardwaj, that did the work just fine  :) (keeping array in a common parent and passing methods and the array top down to child components)